# Error 'no such slot' qt

Tags: qt4, signals-slots, slot

I am trying to connect two widgets through the signals/slots option but I keep getting this error that 'no such slot' exists. The fact is that while writing the program I used Ctrl + Space just to be sure I don't make any typos.

so I have one widget:

renderArea.h

```
    class renderArea : public QGraphicsView
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        renderArea(QWidget *parent = 0);

    void addClothoid(float length, float startCurvature, float endCurvature);

    signals:
        void sendData(float length, float startCurvature, float endCurvature);

    };
```

renderArea.cpp

```
    void renderArea::addClothoid(float length, float startCurvature, float endCurvature)
    {
        ...

            emit sendData(length, startCurvature, endCurvature);
        }
    }
```

the 2nd widget:

tableViewList.h

```
    class TableViewList: public QTableView
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        TableViewList(QWidget* parent = 0);

    protected slots:
        void onClothoidAdded(float length, float startCurvature, float endCurvature);
    };
```

tableViewList.cpp

```
    void TableViewList::onClothoidAdded(float length, float startCurvature, float endCurvature)
    {

    ...
    }
```

and the main widget:

renderingwidget.cpp where i connect the 2 above:

```
    renderingWidget::renderingWidget(QWidget *parent) :
            QWidget(parent),
            ui(new Ui::renderingWidget)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);

    connect(ui->graphicsView, SIGNAL(sendData(float,float,float)), ui->clothoidTable,
                SLOT(onClothoidAdded(float,float,float)));
    }
```

the ui->graphicsView has been promoted to renderArea and the ui->clothoidTable to the TableViewList.

So why could this error be appearing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you re-generate your project files after adding the signal/slots to the class? Depending on your build system this is necessary to make things work.

Qt needs to pre-process the class headers (it does not scan in cpp files) to generate the additional code that implements the signal/slot behaviour (for signal/slots it's using the MOC compiler). If Qt is not aware that class X contains a signal or slot it will just not generate the meta information for that class.

By re-generating the project files/Make file Qt will scan all files again and generate the necessary commands for the MOC compiler.

Comment: Have you checked the generated files by moc to see if the slot is being generated? Maybe deleting all those temp files helps as well (I remember having caching problems once in a while)

Comment: I've checked all the makefiles and there is not mention of my slot in any of them.

Comment: In the make files you have to look for your class headers to appear for MOC processing. MOC creates it's output into a temp folder, it actually creates files like moc_<your classname>.h and moc_<your classname>.cpp. Look into those files to see if your slots show up

Answer (score 1):

Your slot is protected and therefore not visible to `renderingWidget`. You will need to make it public if you want to setup a connection to it from outside `TableViewList`.